# Controlling first name display in biblatex \citeauthor?

Tags: biblatex, citing

Somewhat similar to [Customize `\citeauthor*` to show full author name but UpperCase only the first letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179169/customize-citeauthor-to-show-full-author-name-but-uppercase-only-the-first-l), but I cannot wrap my head around this. Consider this MWE:

```
% pdflatex test.tex; biber test; pdflatex test.tex; pdflatex test.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  style=ieee,
  isbn=true,
  doi=false,
  url=true,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=nyt,
  %sorting=none, % "Do not sort at all. All entries are processed in citation order." (order of appearance)
  firstinits=false, % shows full first name in \printbibliography References
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
% @book{knuth:ct:a,
%   author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
%   title        = {The \TeX book},
%   date         = 1984,

\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{yellow!10}

\begin{document}

As \citeauthor*{knuth:ct:a} noted in \cite{knuth:ct:a}, Tex can be a bit complicated. But as also noted in \cite{knuth:ct:d}, Metafont isn't far behind.

\printbibliography[sorting=none]

\end{document}
```

It currently produces this output:

[image: test.png]

... that is, currently `\citeauthor*{knuth:ct:a}` produces only the last name, "`Knuth`".

I would like to, arbitrarily in the text, use either `\citeauthor*` (with options?) or some other command, so that based on the same citation key, I obtain: a) "`D. Knuth`" (first name as initial, middle name ignored); or b) "`Donald Knuth`" (first name full, middle name ignored). Actually, if it's easier that way, I would appreciate methods that include the middle initial(s) ("`D. E. Knuth`" or "`Donald E. Knuth`") also. Needless to say, I want the reference list to remain as shown. How could I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Well, a more erudite answer will, as always, be appreciated - but for the time being, I got to a workaround, producing this (which includes the middle name initials):

[image: test2.png]

It is not really straightforward, as the name formats '`first-last`' etc have to be looked up in `biblatex.def` (they are not present in the manual), and a hack has to be used to control `firstinits` outside of the preamble; but it seems to work. Here is the MWE:

```
% pdflatex test.tex; biber test; pdflatex test.tex; pdflatex test.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  style=ieee,
  isbn=true,
  doi=false,
  url=true,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=nyt,
  %sorting=none, % "Do not sort at all. All entries are processed in citation order." (order of appearance)
  firstinits=false, % shows full first name
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
% @book{knuth:ct:a,
%   author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
%   title        = {The \TeX book},
%   date         = 1984,

\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{yellow!10}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179169/customize-citeauthor-to-show-full-author-name-but-uppercase-only-the-first-l
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200112/biblatex-extract-authors-seperately/207529#200119
% in biblatex.def: \DeclareNameFormat{first-last}, \DeclareNameFormat{initsonly}, \DeclareNameFormat{labelname}
\makeatletter%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorfin}
  {\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{####1}%
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   % \printnames[initsonly]{author} % too strong, all is initials (D.E.K.)
   %\printnames[firstinits=true,first-last]{author}} % cannot:
   % \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=false} % only in preamble!
   % so must use setkeys:
   \setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{firstinits=true}%
   \printnames[first-last]{author}%
   \setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{firstinits=false}% restore - assuming false is default, which here it is
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorffn}
  {\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{####1}%
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames[first-last]{author}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}

As \citeauthor*{knuth:ct:a} noted in \cite{knuth:ct:a}, Tex can be a bit complicated. But as also noted in \cite{knuth:ct:d}, Metafont isn't far behind. 
Also, "\citeauthorfin{knuth:ct:a}" and "\citeauthorffn{knuth:ct:a}", and "\citeauthor*{knuth:ct:a}" again after that.

\printbibliography[sorting=none]

\end{document}
```