In-Text Citation with Author's last name and initial letter of given name
Let us say my bibliography has the following entry
@book{Doe,
    author = {Doe, John and Carlsson, Martha},
    year = {2013},
    title = {title}
}

Using \citeauthor{Doe} will result in the output

Doe

My question now is the following: Is there a similar command which would output

M. Carlsson and J. Doe

So for all of the stated authors, it should output the first letter from their given name followed by their last name.

Please show a short compilable TeX code -- as usual -- resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing and do not forget the used bib entry!

@Mensch I do not have "an issue", I just do not know which command to use ^^

Well, that depends on the way you are using biblatex and perhaps your used documentclass. Thats the reason why I asked for a short complete, compilable TeX code ...

Please also state what should be done in cases of publications with exactly two authors (say, "Jane Blaine and Martha Carlsson") or with three or more authors. Should the citation call-out say "J. Blaine and M. Carlsson", "J. Doe et al.", or maybe something else?

@Mico Thanks for the comment, I edited my question.

@Mensch I am literally starting with a blank slate currently. This is just a question of "how can it be done".

There is no such command in core biblatex (there only is \citeauthor), but you can modify \citeauthor to give the desired output or define a new command. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24979/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211755/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/612764/35864 very related discussions. Let me know if any of the linked answers helped you. If not, I can write up something below.
